# MAC doFinal gives different value for same data

Tags: java

I am facing an issue with the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String key = "test";
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new 
      SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA512");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
    
    try {
        if (null != mac) {
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        }
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    
    }

    IntStream.range(1, 12).parallel().forEach(d->{
        final byte[] bytes = "somestring".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final byte[]  doFinal= mac.doFinal(bytes);
        String digest = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(doFinal);
        LOGGER.info("digest -- {} ", digest);
    });
}
```

Even the string is the same but digests generated using a mac.doFinal is different. This is just a showcase of the issue. I have used the same code in my spring reactive application where mac is a bean and digest generated every time when user make a request which is a concurrent request where also i have seen these weird behavior.

Comment: You're calling `mac.doFinal` in parallel on a single instance. That sounds like a bad idea to me. Do you get inconsistent results if you just use a regular `for` loop and create the macs in sequence?

Comment: (If you need to perform the operations in parallel, then create a new `Mac` instance in the loop.)

Comment: Sequence loop is fine but there is a real scenario like I have a bean of mac and I have generated a digest of headers using a mac.doFinal() these are the concurrent request on gateway application. Now there is an underlying application that again generates digest for the same data then and compares both digests so that time it will create a problem.

Comment: Concurrent requests should be fine: so long as each one uses a new `Mac` instance. So as I said, for your test code, move the `Mac` creation into the body of the `forEach` lambda. Fundamentally the problem is that you're modifying shared state concurrently - you can't do that and expect the results to be valid.

Comment: Creating a Mac instance every time in a gateway application is an expensive task. I have moved the Mac instance inside forEach it is working fine now but I am not sure the actual reason why mac.doFinal does not generate the same digest for the same data?

Comment: Because you're computing the data for two different values at the same time, so they're interfering with each other. Fundamentally `Mac` isn't designed to be used by this. You may be able to get away with a `ThreadLocal` so you have one `Mac` per thread, reused across threads... but you need to start by accepting that you *can't* use a single `Mac` across multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Is there any alternative other then `Mac`

Comment: No, it's doing exactly what it's designed to do, and that's the way to do it. I've already suggested the solution here: use a ThreadLocal if you want to be able to effectively use a "pool" of shared Mac instances, but only one per thread.